# Interpret Symfony's ACL's schema

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, acl

I'm migrating a system from symfony2 to node. Most of it is going fine, but I've had some trouble understanding how ACL works.
I've got an idea now, but looking at the mysql schema, I see that I have 2 columns with the actual permissions, **ace_order** and **mask**. Can someone please tell me why are there 2 fields instead of only one and/or how to interpret them so I can translate to a simpler schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `acl_entries` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `object_identity_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `security_identity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `field_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `ace_order` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, <== first col
    `mask` int(11) NOT NULL, <== second col
    `granting` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `granting_strategy` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `audit_success` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `audit_failure` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ... other key stuff ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Edit:
I'm mostly interested on how **ace_order** affects the permissions.

Comment: First of all: I don't know.
BUT maybe you find your answer here: https://github.com/symfony/security-acl/blob/master/Domain/PermissionGrantingStrategy.php#L137
I'd open that file in your project (somewhere in vendor folder) and step through the logic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one column that contains the actual permissions, and that is `mask`. This column contains a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29), which is called the "permission mask", which is stored as an integer, which represents the [cumulative permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html#cumulative-permissions) in the ACE.

Other columns can influence if permission is granted:

`ace_order` is used to determine which ACE is checked first. If the ACE's is applicable, it will be used to grant (or deny) permission. If not, the next ACE is checked.

The order is determined by the order of adding ACE's: The last ACE added will have order `0`, the first will have the highest number. As a general rule you should add ACE's from least specific to most specific, meaning the most specific one will be checked first.

`granting` is a boolean (stored as integer) that specifies if the permissions in the ACE are *granted* or *denied*.

`granting_strategy` specifies how the permissions you ask for are compared with the ones in the ACE. In other words: if the ACE is applicable. You can find an explanation in the [source of PermissionGrantingStrategy](https://github.com/symfony/security-acl/blob/master/Domain/PermissionGrantingStrategy.php#L198).

Comment: I'm almost there... do you know how the ace_order number is determined?

Comment: So, the highest ace_order would be the most specific. Right?

Comment: Just experiment with it if you're not sure ;)